# audio_player duration is null on web (flutter)

Tags: flutter-web

I have this code (snippets):

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart' as ap;

final _audioPlayer = ap.AudioPlayer();

await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(widget.source);

final duration = _audioPlayer.duration;
```

Issue is that the duration returned is null - only when run on web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [package example](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) you have to do something like this:

```dart
final player = AudioPlayer();
var duration = await player.setUrl('URL1.mp3');
var duration = await player.setFilePath('PATH/TO/ASSET.mp3');
var duration = await player.setAsset(''PATH/TO/ASSET.mp3');
```

It might be a good idea to take a look at the [readme](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio) and the [example section](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio/example).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I received from the developer on Git:

"Yes, web platform implementation is basic for now.
Most of the features are stubs on it.
You can setup your own timer when starting and stopping the record."

Which is what I did. There is a timer anyway - I changed the period to 100ms and with some changes to the same method, got the duration and the second timer - which I then passed onto the player.

Of course, this means I'll need to save the duration in the dB for playback of a saved file, which might actually be a good idea anyway to display on a player before streaming...